# Typescript just generates "export {};" in the d.ts file

Tags: typescript

When I run the `tsc` command to generate my compiled `dist` directory, typescript seems to generate an empty/wrong d.ts file.

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true
  },
  "lib": ["es2020"],
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

This is my `src/index.ts`:

```
class Test {
   method = (string: string) => {
      console.log(string)
   }
}

module.exports = Test
```

And then after I run `$ tsc`, I get this in my `dist/index.d.ts`:

```
export {};
//# sourceMappingURL=Test.d.ts.map
```

I can confirm by importing the package into a new project as an npm dependency that the import works. I can import `Test` and successfully execute `const test = new Test; test.method('hello world')`. It is only the `.d.ts` file that is not working.

I'm running typescript v4.0.5

Comment: Looks like you have no `ts` files to transpile since you just have a single `js` file only in `src`?

Comment: @tmhao2005 sorry it is actually `src/index.ts`, i just mistyped it into the SO question. I have corrected the question now.

Comment: Hmmm. Which version of `typescript` do you use?

Comment: @tmhao2005  v4.0.5

Comment: The weird thing that I'm aware of is that you code is written in `cjs` style which is supposed to be `esnext` style instead which is likely the issue. Can you change that and try again?

Comment: yes this seems to have been the issue, I updated the `tsconfig.json` to reflect the es2020 module setting.

Comment: Typescript was born to support the `esnext` then convert to various types of different modules. In short, in most cases you should write your code with `esnext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved by doing the following:

1. Changed `tsconfig.json` by updating `"module": "commonjs"` to `"module": "es2020"`
2. In the `.ts` file, change from `module.exports = Test` to `export default Test`

After these changes, the `.d.ts` files were generated properly. The problem was that I was mixing commonjs and ES2020 syntax/settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, i did't success to solve index.d.ts emptiness but in my case:
I've forgot include in my tsconfig:
`"include": [ "src" ]`
and for build i "use react-native-builder-bob" ,
in package.json instead of `"types": "dist/typescript/index.d.ts",` use `"types": "dist/typescript/src/index.d.ts",` and there is no problem for using typing out of the package. i hope this help someone in future